# How to make Tomcat6 on Ubuntu 11.10 run as www-data?

Tags: web-server, tomcat

How to change the user tomcat runs, to www-data?

I tried the same thing as [How to run tomcat6 on ubuntu as root?](https://serverfault.com/questions/135858/how-to-run-tomcat6-on-ubuntu-as-root) but it doesnt cause any changes.

Comment: how did you install tomcat?

Comment: `apt-get install tomcat6`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I just did it with tomcat6 installed..

I first stopped tomcat from running

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat6 stop
```

Changed the following in

```
/etc/default/tomcat6
```

To be the following

```
# Run Tomcat as this user ID. Not setting this or leaving it blank will use the
# default of tomcat6.
TOMCAT6_USER=www-data

# Run Tomcat as this group ID. Not setting this or leaving it blank will use
# the default of tomcat6.
TOMCAT6_GROUP=www-data
```

Then I had to change ownership of the log directory

```
chown -R www-data: /var/log/tomcat6
chown -R www-data: /usr/lib/tomcat6
chown -R www-data: /etc/tomcat6
```

Then I was able to run tomcat6

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat6 start
```

See the results

```
# ps aux | grep tomcat
www-data 26436 11.3  0.7 559552 58464 ?        Sl   05:34   0:01 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat6/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat6 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat6 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat6-tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Comment: There were silent failures till I set the ownership of /usr/lib/tomcat6 and /etc/tomcat6 . Only then Tomcat served my application. Please include these crucial pieces.

Comment: same for `/var/cache/tomcat6/`. Tomcat will complain about an unwritable scratch dir